# How to squash Django migrations with lazy references?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django 1.11 project and I'm trying to squash all migrations by deleting and re-making all of them.

However, when I go to run `manage.py makemigrations` I get an error like:

```
ValueError: The field app1.Model1.campaign was declared with a lazy reference to 'app2.Campaign', but app 'app2' isn't installed.
```

However, app2 is definitely installed. I even print out my `INSTALLED_APPS` list in my `settings.py` to confirm it is. What's causing this error?

Comment: Try to delete all migrations(if it's not important to save all of them), delete all data from `django_migrations` table in DB and run `makemigrations` again